# jquery-selectBox does not support on tablet and mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have used this type of plugin.
**https://github.com/marcj/jquery-selectBox**

but This plugin funcationality work well . but problem is that select dropdown does not look very well on tablet and mobile device.

I have used this code.

```
$('select').selectBox();
$('select').selectBox('settings', {
   mobile: true
});
```

there is any solution ? otherwise I have to change the plugin .

and I want to know one more thing that Does this plugin support on mobile device ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a mobile solution you should either add some css with media queries or you need to use another plugin:

As the Settings from SelectBox only states:

"Setting: mobile"
"Default: false"
"Type:Boolean"
"Description: Disables the widget for mobile devices"

Comment: Thanks, can you provide the any select box plugin that work well on mobile device and web also.

Comment: I recommend using the jQuery SelectBoxIt Plugin from Here: http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/ there are mobile demos and so on